# minimum number of iteration in Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

One root of the equation $e^{x}-3x^{2}=0$ lies in the interval $(3,4)$, the least number of iterations of the bisection method, so that $|\text{Error}|<10^{-3}$ is

(a) $10$

(b) $6$

(c) $8$

(d) $4$

Comment: $10^{3}$?? Isn't it $10^{\color{red}{-}3}$

Comment: @Surb what do you mean?

Comment: I assume you mean $10^{-3}$. In this case it will be $-\log_2(10^{-3})$ (possibly plus or minus one depending on how you define the start and end of the algorithm).

Comment: Yes...It was a mistake....

Comment: How we find out the solution of this type of problems?

Comment: For any numerical method, it is very hard to find a non-trivial *lower* bound on the convergence rate (or iteration counts) a priori which strongly depends on how lucky your initial guess is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very easy. For [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Analysis) we always have
$$n\ge \frac{\log{(b-a)}-\log{\epsilon}}{\log2}$$
Here we have $\epsilon=10^{-3}$, $a=3$, $b=4$ and $n$ is the number of iterations
$$n\ge \frac{\log{(1)}-\log{10^{-3}}}{\log2}\approx 9.9658$$
Then $n=10$.

Comment: The number of iterations can be less than this, if the root happens to land near enough to a point $x = 3 + \frac{m}{2^{n}}, \; m = 0,1,\dots, 2^{n},$ where $n$ is the iteration number.  For example, if the root was at $x = 3.5001,$ 10 iterations wouldn't be necessary to achieve the error bound.  10 is an upper bound, the question seeks the least number of iterations.

Comment: Do you round the result of the expression up or down? Or do you simply round to the nearest whole number?

Answer (score 0):

The number of bisection steps is simply equal to the number of binary digits you gain from the initial interval (you are dividing by 2). Then it's a simple conversion from decimal digits to binary digits.